# Pass same arguments to another function in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create a util class which has helper functions that create example objects for use in unit tests.  For each object I have, I'm simply providing a `createXYZExample` function where all of the named optional arguments are given default values and the functions simply return a new instance of the object, created with all of the same arguments. Here's an example:

```
class MyClass{
  String param1;
  String param2;
  String param3;
  MyClass({this.param1, this.param2, this.param3});
}

MyClass createMyClassExample({
  String param1 = 'default Param1',
  String param2 = 'default Param2',
  String param3 = 'default Param3',
}) => MyClass(
  param1: param1, 
  param2: param2, 
  param3: param3
);
```

You can see that my 'createMyClassExample' function has a lot of boiler plate in repeating the params, this becomes even more painful for classes with a large number of optional parameters.  Is there some way to do something like this?

```
MyClass createMyClassExample({
  String param1 = 'default Param1',
  String param2 = 'default Param2',
  String param3 = 'default Param3',
}) => MyClass(arguments);
```

If not, is there some better way to do this so I'm not having to add so much repeated code for the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I if understand you correctly, you need some method like `copyWith`:

```
class MyClass {
  String param1;
  String param2;
  String param3;
  MyClass({
    required this.param1,
    required this.param2,
    required this.param3,
  });

  MyClass copyWith({
    String? param1,
    String? param2,
    String? param3,
  }) =>
      MyClass(
        param1: param1 ?? this.param1,
        param2: param2 ?? this.param2,
        param3: param3 ?? this.param3,
      );
}

final myClass = MyClass(
  param1: 'default Param1',
  param2: 'default Param2',
  param3: 'default Param3',
);

final myClass2 = myClass.copyWith(
  param1: 'new param1',
);

final myClass3 = myClass.copyWith(
  param2: 'new param2',
  param3: 'new param3',
);
```